# Assigning a null value to an int

Tags: java

If the following code is possible:

```
Integer a = null;
int b = a;
```

Does it mean that a function returning a possible `null` value for an integer is a bad practice?

Edit 1:
There are several different opinions in these answers. I am not enough confident to choose one or another.

Comment: Tony Hoare, the inventor of null, calls it his billion dollar mistake. Avoid `null` in general.

Comment: It's not bad practice if you need to know that the value is unknown. Exception handling for `NullPointerException` can be incorporated into your code to reflect the absence, convert the NULL INT to a zero, etc. [NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) is a necessary evil, there are cases where you need to clearly identify an unknown or absence of value, such as: how many times will I get married, date of death, etc.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline so all we know is that he was wrong at least once, when that was is not only up for debate but also off topic. Considering that this question is not about language design and null is very much integral part of java stating the believes of a language designer is also unhelpfull

Answer (score 50, accepted):

That code will give a `NullPointerException` when you run it. It's basically equivalent to:

```
Integer a = null;
int b = a.intValue();
```

... which makes it clearer that it will indeed fail.

You're not *really* assigning a null value to an `int` - you're trying and failing.

It's fine to use `null` as a value for an `Integer`; indeed often `Integer` is used instead of `int` precisely as a "nullable equivalent`.

Comment: If your function return an Integer, then when this function will be call, it should be assign to an Integer instead of an int in order to avoid this kind of exception. Otherwise it will be risky no?

Comment: @JohnJohnGa: Well yes. But then presumably if the method is returning `Integer` rather than `int`, that's intentionally *because* it might be null.

Comment: @FrankComputer: Not in Java it can't. It's not really clear why you've added this comment, to be honest...

Comment: I added the comment because sometimes there's a legitimate need for an integer to have a null value.

Comment: @FrankComputer: I think the OP's already aware of that, and bringing C# into a Java question (without even saying so) is more likely to add confusion than clarity, IMO.

Answer (score 14):

It is not possible. You will get `NullPointerException`

Comment: Depend how you define possible. It will successfully compile.

Comment: @JohnJohnGa:`NullPointerException` occurs in runtime.Not sure what you mean.Do you want correct code or code that compiles?

Answer (score 6):

That will throw a NullPointerException.

The reason for this is that you're relying on auto-unboxing of the Integer value to an int primitive type. Java does this by internally calling `.intValue()` on the Object, which is null.

As to either it's a good practice or not... I would advise against doing so, unless the code is only used by you and you're extremely well behaved, making sure that you only assign the return value of such method to Integer values, not int.

If your code ends up in a lib used by others, it's not safe, and I would rather explicitly throw an Exception, well documented, and allow for defensive coding on the caller's part.

Answer (score 3):

Funny thing with Java tenerary operator ?: (using 8u151 on OSX)

If you do

```
Integer x = map == null ? 0 : map.get ( key );
```

which seems fine and compact and all, then you get an npe!!! if

```
map.get ( key )
```

is a null. So I had to split that and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you cannot assign null to an int. But returning a null in some situations makes sense. Null can mean that the value is not set. A typical example is a DB column.

Answer (score 2):

The code *is* possible, but throws a `NullPointerException` at runtime, because of unboxing. Regarding

> Does it mean that a function returning a possible null value for an
>   integer is a bad practice?

yes, it is. It's useless and dangerous (as you can see) to return an `Integer` when a `int` is enough, because objects can be null, while primitives can't. `Integer` should be used only when needed, like in a parameterized type - `List<Integer>`

Answer (score 2):

From Java 8, we can use Optional:

```
// example: if an Integer object is null, an int value could receive 0, for example:

Integer value = getSomeInteger (...); // (0, null, or some other numeric value)
int inteiro = Optional.ofNullable(value).orElse(0);
```

Comment: Note that `Optional.ofNullable()` method call requires API level 24 and higher

Answer (score 1):

That would work indeed.

```
Integer a = null;
Integer b = a;
```

But I would rather use a int value out of range (-1 if your numbers are all positive) to return in case of an error.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bout Java auto-boxing.

```
Integer a = null;
int b = a;
```

this code assign a to b,actually the compiler will do this:int b=a.intValue(), so this line will throw NullPointerException;

the code :

```
Integer a = 1;
```

will actually do this: Integer a = Integer.valueOf(1);

You can use **javap** to see the compiled virtual machine instructions。

Answer (score 1):

You can write simple test:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer a = null;
        int b = a;

        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

And the output is a NullPointerException on `int b = a;`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main(Test.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```